# getting .a instead of .lib when building Qt from source

Tags: linux, windows, qt, .a, .lib

I was building Qt 6.4 from source following [these](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/windows-building.html) instructions on Windows.

I put '-static' as an argument when configuring with 'configure.bat' but after building i found only .a files instead of .lib. Then i checked configure and 'configure.bat' but i didn't find any parameters in which you are specifying what OS you are using.

What am i doing wrong and how to get .lib files instead of unix-like .a?

Comment: `.a` is the expected file extension for static libraries for g++, and clang regardless of the OS. `.lib` is the correct extension for Microsoft's msvc compiler on MS Windows.

Comment: ***What am i doing wrong*** Your expectations are wrong  ***and how to get .lib files instead of unix-like .a?*** Build with msvc and you will get `.lib` files usable for msvc. Note that you usually can't mix compilers so the binaries produced with msvc are for msvc only (or possibly clang since there is a msvc compatibility mode).